# Calling functions within function in MySQL returns NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't understand why when I call my SQL Function inside another Function values are lost. Basically I have something like this:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION `myCustomFunctionA`(paramOne INTEGER, paramTwo INTEGER) RETURNS INT(11)
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE outputOne INT(11);  
    DECLARE outputTwo INT(11);      

    SET outputOne = myCustomFunctionB(paramOne);  
    SET outputTwo = myCustomFunctionB(paramTwo);        

 RETURN myCustomFunctionC(outputOne, outputTwo);
END
```

*Please note that all of these functions return each an integer when called outside myCustomFunctionA. I.E: Running **SELECT myCustomFunctionB(paramTwo);** actually returns X value and same for paramOne. However when these functions are called inside myCustomFunctionA it's always returning NULL.*

*So far I tried to return directly paramOne and paramTwo and values are correct. But if I set function to return outputOne or outputTwo after running myCustomFunctionB then they'd also return NULL.*

This seems to be something silly I'm missing but I can't see it so any help or tip in the right direction would be really apprecciated. Thanks.